# Office 2010 OCT Outlook Filepaths

Tags: outlook-2010, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010

I'm playing around with customizing Office 2010 installs on my network, normally I just do a full manual install, but as the environment grows and the lazier I get its becoming a pain to do it manually every time. I've read up and downloaded the Office 2010 OCT tool and it looks relatively straight forward - with one exception - the Outlook Profile.

I can 'get around it' by just leaving it all as default (or not enabling offline use) but I'd like to customise it slightly so that its all setup no matter who logs onto the PC. The only issue I have, and my question is:

In the OCT - Outlook section **What do you enter into the Path and Filename for the OST file and the Offline Address book seetings under Enable Offline Use section?**

I'm sweet with everything else - just that one section, and I think if I bugger that one it will kill the whole Outlook Profile?? It would need to go into each users unique filepath for their profile correct? I have a fair idea of what should be there but I'm struggling with the correct syntax.

I know this is a stupid question....but its late in the day and my brain is  fried ;)

As usual - any and all help/assistance is appreciated ;)

Comment: Haven't done that before, However this link may help...http://myitforum.com/myitforumwp/2012/07/02/office-2010-oct-and-outlook-settings/

Comment: close, but no cigar sadly :(

Comment: I think the default path should be - `%userprofile%\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook` folder. The default location for the .ost file , For Microsoft Windows 2000, Microsoft Windows NT, Microsoft Windows XP and Microsoft Windows Server 2003 is 
`C:\Documents and Settings\user name\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook`

Comment: For Windows 7 & Windows Vista     `drive:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook`.This link should be helpful - http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/outlook-help/where-does-microsoft-outlook-2010-save-my-information-and-configurations-HP010354943.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The default location for offline files and the OAB is the same.

Default location in Windows Vista and newer versions can be formatted like this:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Outlook\
or
%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook
```

On Windows XP, it would be:

```
%userprofile%\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Outlook
```

Comment: So the correct procedure would be to create two custom Office installs, one for Vista and above with the first setting and a second install for any XP machines i have left with the second?

I'll take a crack and report back, cheers ;)